# C# UpdateListBox method declaration in user defined class

Tags: c#, listbox

Hey in a user defined class called Dog, i have a list which stores a list of Dog objects:

```
List<Dog> dogList = new List<Dog>();
```

And on the main form I have a listBox control called dogListBox.

In the class I;m trying to create a method which updates the listBox control. however, when i try declare it I get errors under dogListBox saying that dogListBox does not exist in the current context. How can I access the listBox control on my form to use in this method

Thanks

```
public void UpdateListbox()
{
    dogListBox.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Dog dog in dogListBox)
    {
        dogListBox.Items.Add(dog);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the rest of your form? I suspect the problem is outside of the code you initially posted.

Answer (score 0):

in the class that has this UpdateListBox, you need access to the listbox on the form  ( which is another class)

So you either need to pass the list box to the UpdateListBox method.... or you need to store a reference to the Form in the class.

or you add a method on the form to update the listbox with a list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense because you never use dogList.  Is UpdateListBox a method in your form in the dog class?  It should be a method in your form.  Then you can write something like:

```
public void UpdateListbox()
        {
            dogListBox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Dog dog in dog.dogList)
            {
                dogListBox.Items.Add(dog);
            }
        }
```

The form should be updating the listbox not the dog.

I also want to mention that even if the above works, its logically incorrect because a dog should not have a list of dogs.  But thats another issue.